# Creating a pivot table in pandas and grouping at the same time the dates per week

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a `pd.pivot_table` in `python` where one column is a `datetime` object, but I want also, to group my results on a weekly basis. Here's a simple example: I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] * 7
dates = ['2017-01-11', '2017-01-08', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-13', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-08', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-12']
dates = [pd.to_datetime(i).date() for i in dates]
numbers = [4, 3, 2, 1 ] * 7
data = {'name': names , 'date': dates, 'number': numbers}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which yields:

```
          date name  number
0   2017-01-11    a       4
1   2017-01-08    b       3
2   2017-01-14    c       2
3   2017-01-05    d       1
4   2017-01-10    a       4
5   2017-01-13    b       3
6   2017-01-02    c       2
7   2017-01-12    d       1
8   2017-01-10    a       4
9   2017-01-05    b       3
10  2017-01-01    c       2
11  2017-01-04    d       1
12  2017-01-11    a       4
13  2017-01-14    b       3
14  2017-01-05    c       2
15  2017-01-06    d       1
16  2017-01-14    a       4
17  2017-01-11    b       3
18  2017-01-06    c       2
19  2017-01-05    d       1
20  2017-01-08    a       4
21  2017-01-10    b       3
22  2017-01-07    c       2
23  2017-01-04    d       1
24  2017-01-02    a       4
25  2017-01-04    b       3
26  2017-01-01    c       2
27  2017-01-12    d       1
```

I want to create a pivot table where the rows are going to be the *names*, the columns are going to be the dates on a **weekly** basis and the numbers are going to be the sum of the number column. For example, the first row of the pivot table will be:

`2017-01-01                2017-01-08               2017-01-15 ...
 a            4                         24                         0`

What I am doing is:

`pd.pivot_table(data=df, values='number', columns=pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1W'), index='name', aggfunc=sum)`

but I get the Error:
`TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'.`

How am I supposed to do that? I don't know if I can use the date as an index, since all the date values are not unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC:

first make sure that the `date` column is of `datetime` dtype:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
```

then you can group, sum and unstack:

```
In [289]: (df.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date')])
             ['number']
             .sum()
             .unstack(fill_value=0))
Out[289]:
date  2017-01-01  2017-01-08  2017-01-15
name
a              0           8          20
b              0           9          12
c              4           8           2
d              0           5           2
```

or as [proposed by @thanasissdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860292/creating-a-pivot-table-in-pandas-and-grouping-at-the-same-time-the-dates-per-wee/47860321#comment82685717_47860321):

```
In [328]: (df.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date', closed='left')])
             ['number']
             .sum()
             .unstack(fill_value=0))
Out[328]:
date  2017-01-08  2017-01-15
name
a              4          24
b              6          15
c             12           2
d              5           2
```

or

```
In [330]: (df.assign(date=df['date']-pd.offsets.Day(7))
     ...:    .groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date', closed='left')])
     ...:    ['number']
     ...:    .sum()
     ...:    .unstack(fill_value=0))
     ...:
Out[330]:
date  2017-01-01  2017-01-08
name
a              4          24
b              6          15
c             12           2
d              5           2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the results are not the same as the desired ones.

Comment: @thanasissdr, can you explain how did you get those numbers in the desired / resulting data set? What should happen to the `name` column?

Comment: Sure. The first entry will be the sum of the numbers in the column 'number' which correspond to name 'a'. The first element `0` corresponds to the period `2017-01-01` up to `2017-01-07`(inclusive). The second element `24` corresponds to the period `2017-01-08` up to `2017-01-14`(inclusive) e.t.c.

Comment: It is sufficient to pass an argument `closed='left'`.

Comment: But still there are some issues. The elements for the first column for b, c and d are missing.

Comment: @thanasissdr, the whole data set spans over 13 days: `df.date.max() - df.date.min()`. Why do you expect to see three columns there?

Comment: Damn, you are right! I didn't pay attention to  the dates!!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with my logic, we can create a **multi-index**, where the *date* is part of the index.  So we can have:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] * 7
dates = ['2017-01-11', '2017-01-08', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-13', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-08', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-12']
dates = [pd.to_datetime(i).date() for i in dates]
numbers = [4, 3, 2, 1 ] * 7
data = {'name': names , 'date': dates, 'number': numbers}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.set_index([df.index, df.date], inplace=True)

print pd.pivot_table(data=df, columns=pd.Grouper(freq='7d', level='date', closed='left') , index='name', aggfunc=sum)
```

which yields exactly:

```
         number           
date 2017-01-01 2017-01-08
name                      
a             4         24
b             6         15
c            12          2
d             5          2
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby(['name', 'date'])['number'].sum().unstack()
```

Explanation:

1. groupby name and date.
2. Pick number from group
3. Sum all numbers and unstack