# How can I join column values from DataFrame groups?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

### Problem

I would like to group my DataFrame entries by intervals of two years, join the column values with a delimiter "#", and join entries in the same interval with a delimiter ";".

I have previously achieved this by [iterating through the years and creating a new DataFrame](https://pastebin.com/MZxsyYK3), but it's quite messy—I would much prefer a vectorized solution.

Example input:

```
  dx_code patient_id                           dx_name  year
0  427.31    Z324563     Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)  2012
1   H53.9    Z324563                Visual disturbance  2014
2     725    Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2009
3     725    Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011
4    None    Z273652    Disorder of bone and cartilage  2004
5   272.0    Z273652         Pure hypercholesterolemia  2006
6  729.81    Z273652                  Swelling of limb  2012
7   446.5    Z273652    Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)  2010
8     725    Z273652  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011
```

Example output:

```
  patient_id                         2004–2005_dx  \
0    Z324563                                 None   
1    Z273652  None#Disorder of bone and cartilage   

                      2006–2007_dx                          2008–2009_dx  \
0                             None  725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)   
1  272.0#Pure hypercholesterolemia                                  None   

                                                                 2010–2011_dx  \
0                                        725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)   
1  446.5#Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC); 725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)   

                           2012–2013_dx                   2014_dx  \
0  427.31#Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)  H53.9#Visual disturbance   
1               729.81#Swelling of limb                      None   

  unknown_time_dx  
0            None  
1            None
```

### What I've tried

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860321) answer, I have the following code:

```
self.data.groupby(["patient_id", pd.Grouper(freq="2Y", key="date")])
                .sum()
                .unstack(fill_value=""))
```

It outputs the following:

```
              dx_code                                                                     dx_name                                                                                                                                    
date       2004-12-31 2006-12-31 2010-12-31 2012-12-31 2014-12-31                      2004-12-31                 2006-12-31                        2010-12-31                                         2012-12-31          2014-12-31
patient_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Z273652             0      272.0      446.5  729.81725             Disorder of bone and cartilage  Pure hypercholesterolemia    Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)   Swelling of limbPolymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)                    
Z324563                                 725  427.31725      H53.9                                                             Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)Polymyalgia rheum...  Visual disturbance
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to combine column values from the two groups.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's create the starting DataFrame:

```
content = """  dx_code  patient_id  dx_name  year
0  427.31  Z324563  Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)  2012
1  H53.9  Z324563  Visual disturbance  2014
2  725  Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2009
3  725  Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011
4  None  Z273652  Disorder of bone and cartilage  2004
5  272.0  Z273652  Pure hypercholesterolemia  2006
6  729.81  Z273652  Swelling of limb  2012
7  446.5  Z273652  Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)  2010
8  725  Z273652  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011
"""
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), 
            sep='  ')
print(df)

  dx_code patient_id                           dx_name  year
0  427.31    Z324563     Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)  2012
1   H53.9    Z324563                Visual disturbance  2014
2     725    Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2009
3     725    Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011
4    None    Z273652    Disorder of bone and cartilage  2004
5   272.0    Z273652         Pure hypercholesterolemia  2006
6  729.81    Z273652                  Swelling of limb  2012
7   446.5    Z273652    Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)  2010
8     725    Z273652  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011
```

Now, define the bins:

```
import numpy as np
#b = [0,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,np.inf] # you can make the list if you wish (I suggest start with 0 and finish with np.inf)
b = [x for x in range(2002,2020,2)] # or just to use bigger ranges
```

so

```
df_cut = df.assign(PopGroup=pd.cut(df.year,bins=b))
print(df_cut)
  dx_code patient_id                           dx_name  year      PopGroup
0  427.31    Z324563     Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)  2012  (2010, 2012]
1   H53.9    Z324563                Visual disturbance  2014  (2012, 2014]
2     725    Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2009  (2008, 2010]
3     725    Z324563  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011  (2010, 2012]
4    None    Z273652    Disorder of bone and cartilage  2004  (2002, 2004]
5   272.0    Z273652         Pure hypercholesterolemia  2006  (2004, 2006]
6  729.81    Z273652                  Swelling of limb  2012  (2010, 2012]
7   446.5    Z273652    Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)  2010  (2008, 2010]
8     725    Z273652  Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)  2011  (2010, 2012]
```

Let's join the columns dx_code and dx_name:

```
df_cut['DX_code_name'] = df_cut[['dx_code', 'dx_name']].agg('#'.join, axis=1)
print(df_cut)
  dx_code patient_id  ...      PopGroup                          DX_code_name
0  427.31    Z324563  ...  (2010, 2012]  427.31#Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)
1   H53.9    Z324563  ...  (2012, 2014]              H53.9#Visual disturbance
2     725    Z324563  ...  (2008, 2010]  725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)
3     725    Z324563  ...  (2010, 2012]  725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)
4    None    Z273652  ...  (2002, 2004]   None#Disorder of bone and cartilage
5   272.0    Z273652  ...  (2004, 2006]       272.0#Pure hypercholesterolemia
6  729.81    Z273652  ...  (2010, 2012]               729.81#Swelling of limb
7   446.5    Z273652  ...  (2008, 2010]  446.5#Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)
8     725    Z273652  ...  (2010, 2012]  725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)
```

And finnally we use pivot_table:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df_cut, 
                       values=['DX_code_name'], 
                       index=['patient_id'],
                    columns=['year'],
                    aggfunc=lambda x: '# '.join(x),
                    fill_value=np.nan
                    )
```

Let's see:

```
table
DX_code_name
year    2004    2006    2009    2010    2011    2012    2014
patient_id                          
Z273652 None#Disorder of bone and cartilage 272.0#Pure hypercholesterolemia NaN 446.5#Giant cell arteritis (CMS/HCC)    725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)    729.81#Swelling of limb NaN
Z324563 NaN NaN 725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)    NaN 725#Polymyalgia rheumatica (CMS/HCC)    427.31#Atrial fibrillation (CMS/HCC)    H53.9#Visual disturbance
```